# dropdown menu with links to the functions

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I currently have two buttons. 1 to change a mysql variable to 1 and one to change it to 0
This works fine but i would like to have them in a dropdown. So i dont have 2 buttons showing.

```
<td>
    <a href="<?=base_url();?>taak/taak_complete?cct=<?=$row->idTaak;?>"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></a>
    <a href="<?=base_url();?>taak/taak_incomplete?cit=<?=$row->idTaak;?>"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></a>
</td>
```

the first one sets "complete" to 1 and the second one sets "complete" to 0.

Comment: Do you have the above code inside a form?

Comment: You could change hrefs to <select> and on change redirect to url based on picked option. You can consider also additional button to send request, as user might accidentialy pick option and it will automaticly redirect him. This solution will need some javascript, but you wont have to change your code to form and to manage it in php. If you don mind using form it will be even better, but need some changes in php.

Comment: No i dont have it in a form

Comment: then create dropdown with onchange event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare options array as below

```
$opts=array(
    '' =>'--Select--',
    '0'=>'Option 1',
    '1'=>'Option 2'
);
```

Generate dropdown with below CI Code:

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('dropdown_name',$opts,'','onchange="gotopage(this.value)"');?>
```

In js:

```
function gotopage(val)
{
   if(val!="")
   {
      window.location = "<?php echo site_url("PATH_TO_GO");?>/"+val; // pass parameter in url
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code only we can tell you in general what to do to make a drop down in codeignitor. In your view page, you should put this to generate a select combination box. The value can be received only if, its in a form. if you don't want a form, then you may need to incorporate Ajax with this.

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('cmb',$select_options,'0');?>
```

The first variable will become the name of the variable and the third variable is the default option that that has to be select (in this case Option 1 will be selected). The third variable is the data array which contains the options of the dropdown.

The data array, have to be like this, which have to be passed from controller into the view.

```
$select_options=array(
    '0'=>'Option 1';
    '1'=>'Option 2'
);
```